# Implementing Facebook Pixel using Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, facebook-pixel

I've been trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58120781/2803757) post r.e setting up Facebook Pixel, but getting a few errors when compiling - I've commented inline where it's flagging the errors.

**Here is my facebook-pixel-service.ts file:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FacebookPixelService {
  private loadOk = false;

  constructor() {}

  load() {
    if (!this.loadOk) {
      (function(f: any, b, e, v, n, t, s) { // Getting 'non-arrow functions are forbidden' warning
        if (f.fbq) {
          return;
        }
        n = f.fbq = function() { // Getting Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
          n.callMethod
            ? n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments)
            : n.queue.push(arguments);
        };
        if (!f._fbq) {
          f._fbq = n;
        }
        n.push = n;
        n.loaded = !0;
        n.version = '2.0';
        n.queue = [];
        t = b.createElement(e); // Getting Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
        t.async = !0;
        t.src = v;
        s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s);
      })(
        window,
        document,
        'script',
        'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js',
      );
      (window as any).fbq('init', {fbPixelId});
      (window as any).fbq('track', 'PageView');
      this.loadOk = true;
      console.log('Facebook pixel init run!');
    } else {
      (window as any).fbq('track', 'PageView');
      console.log('Facebook PageView event fired!');
    }
  }
}
```

I've implemented the suggested *service* and *provider* files, however I'm getting these errors when compiling the app:

1.) 'non-arrow functions are forbidden' warning **(RESOLVED)**

2.) Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'undefined' **(commented inline)**

3.) Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'undefined' **(commented inline)**

4.) For every instance of each function param is being assigned, it's throwing *Object is possibly 'undefined'*

Thanks in advance

**EDIT - 30/03/2020**

Changing `(function(f: any, b, e, v, n, t, s) {` to `((f: any, b, e, v, n, t, s) => {` and `n = f.fbq = function() {` to `n = f.fbq = () => {` has resolved the non-arrow warning.

All errors are now resolved by adjusting the signature to follow TypeScripts optional chaining, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58401023/6620085)

So the final signature should look something like this:
`((f: any, b, e, v, n?: any, t?: any, s?: any) => {`

Answer (score 3):

in the first place you need to paste the pixel in the index HTML, then you could create a service that will be in charge of generating events for FB pixel.
This way.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

declare var fbq: Function;

@Injectable()
export class MarketingService {

  public onEventFacebook(event: IMarketing) {
    fbq('track', event.eventCategory, {
      content_name: event.eventLabel,
      content_category: event.eventCategory,
      content_ids: [],
      content_type: event.eventAction,
      value: event.eventValue,
      currency: 'ARS'
    });
  }

  public setEventData(eventCategory, eventAction, eventLabel): IMarketing {
    return {
      eventCategory,
      eventAction,
      eventLabel,
      eventValue: 0
    };
  }

}
```

After that, you will call it in this way

```
  const eventData: IMarketing = this.mktService.setEventData(
        'Registration',
        `new-${provider}-account`,
        'Nuevo usuario Registrado',
      );

      this.mktService.onEventFacebook(eventData);
```